# layout is not shown after waiting

Tags: android, layout

I have three layouts:

```
Layout1
-->onClick()-->show
Layout2
-->wait three seconds-->show
Layout3
```

The problem is that Layout2 is not shown. To set the layouts I use

```
setContentView(int);
```

The relevant code might be:

```
public class TrainingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
        final Button inputButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inputButton);
        inputButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    changeLayouts();
            }
         });
    }
    public void changeLayouts() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.layout3);
    }
}
```

My idea was that Android might use something like an "Event-Loop" (like Qt) and my method would block the control to get back to the "Event-Loop" which would make the layout displayed.
But I couldn't find my error.

Comment: rethink your design. why would you have setContentView more than once for the same activity in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure why this specifically is failing, I'm surprised it's not throwing a NotResponding.  If you want some action to trigger a UI action after a three second pause, consider using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why your `layout2` is not shown is because of `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);` - what you are doing here is you put your UI thread into sleep, so UI thread cannot process your request to change layout. And when it wakes up - it immediately sets `layout3` that's why `layout2` is not shown.

You might consider using [`Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to postpone execution

So this should work as you expected:

```
public class TrainingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
        final Button inputButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inputButton);
        inputButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    changeLayouts();
            }
         });
    }
    public void changeLayouts() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout3);
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will surely work

```
    public void changeLayouts() {
         setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

        Thread Timer = new Thread(){
       public void run(){
          try{
              sleep(3000);
          } catch(InterruptedException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
               setContentView(R.layout.layout3);                
          }
       }    
    }; Timer.start();
}
```